# Concatenating repeated XML element result in single row XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

> I am trying to concatenate the repeating OrderID into single row output with delimiter comma(,). buy my xslt is not giving expected output. Any light thrown on this would be appreciated.

**My XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <EventsRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Event>
   <Item>
     <ID>ID1</ID>
     <TABLE_NAME>TABLE_NAME</TABLE_NAME>        
     <ORDERID>111,US</ORDERID>
     <STATUS>INPROGRESS</STATUS>
     <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
     <SUBSCRIBED_BY>AAA</SUBSCRIBED_BY>        
   </Item>
   <Item>
     <ID>ID12</ID>
     <TABLE_NAME>TABLE_NAME</TABLE_NAME>        
     <ORDERID>222,US</ORDERID>
     <STATUS>INPROGRESS</STATUS>
     <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
     <SUBSCRIBED_BY>BBB</SUBSCRIBED_BY>      
   </Item>
  </Event>  
 </EventsRequest>
```

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="EventsRequest/Event/Item">
     <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(ORDERID, ',')">
        <DAILIYORDERS>
           <OrderIds>
              <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,',')"/>
           </OrderIds>
        </DAILIYORDERS>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<DAILIYORDERS>
<OrderIds>111</OrderIds>  
</DAILIYORDERS>
<DAILIYORDERS>  
<OrderIds>222</OrderIds>
</DAILIYORDERS>
```

**Expected Output**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DAILIYORDERS>
  <OrderIds>111,222</OrderIds>
</DAILIYORDERS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you expect can be obtained simply by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/EventsRequest">
    <DAILIYORDERS>
        <OrderIds>
            <xsl:value-of select="Event/Item/substring-before(ORDERID, ',')" separator=","/>
        </OrderIds>
    </DAILIYORDERS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```